# How can you know the sequence/names of the bands of a GeoTIFF file in Java?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, java, geotools, satellite

I want to know the sequence of the bands (4 and more) of a GeoTIFF file for example whether the sequence is blue, green, red, near infra red, temperature, etc or green, blue, ...

How can I know that in Java, for example in GeoTools library? And by the way, are there specific tags in the GeoTIFF that indicates that (like TIFFTAG_IMAGEDESCRIPTION) or it is up to the image reader software to interpret the bands (even if it assumes the sequence mistakenly and considers blue instead of red and so forth).

Answer (score 1):

In GeoTools you can find out the names of the bands and make a guess as to the RGB order but that is all it is a guess.

Consider the following code from the [image tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/raster/image.html):

```
int numBands = cov.getNumSampleDimensions();
// Get the names of the bands
String[] sampleDimensionNames = new String[numBands];
for (int i = 0; i < numBands; i++) {
  GridSampleDimension dim = cov.getSampleDimension(i);
  sampleDimensionNames[i] = dim.getDescription().toString();
}
final int RED = 0, GREEN = 1, BLUE = 2;
int[] channelNum = { -1, -1, -1 };
// We examine the band names looking for "red...", "green...", "blue...".
// Note that the channel numbers we record are indexed from 1, not 0.
for (int i = 0; i < numBands; i++) {
  String name = sampleDimensionNames[i].toLowerCase();
  if (name != null) {
    if (name.matches("red.*")) {
      channelNum[RED] = i + 1;
    } else if (name.matches("green.*")) {
      channelNum[GREEN] = i + 1;
    } else if (name.matches("blue.*")) {
      channelNum[BLUE] = i + 1;
    }
  }
}
// If we didn't find named bands "red...", "green...", "blue..."
// we fall back to using the first three bands in order
if (channelNum[RED] < 0 || channelNum[GREEN] < 0 || channelNum[BLUE] < 0) {
  channelNum[RED] = 1;
  channelNum[GREEN] = 2;
  channelNum[BLUE] = 3;
}
```

If for example your bands are called by other names (like band 1, 2 & 3) then you need to refer to the metadata that came with the file.